# Выборка из mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть 2 таблицы: `users` и `objects`.
В `users` хранятся *id, name, type* и т.д.
В `objects` хранятся *id, user_id* и т.д
Вопрос: как одним запросом сделать выборку в таблице `objects` всех значений, где *type* в `users` равно, к примеру, 2

Comment: `inner join` и where по type=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT o.id, o.user_id 
FROM objects AS o 
INNER JOIN users AS u ON o.user_id = u.id
WHERE u.type = 2
```

Comment: В таком случае выбирается первая строка в таблице `object`. А как выбрать все строки?

Comment: Выбираются - все. Скорее всего, Вы смотрите инструментом, который показывает только одну запись.

Comment: все, разобрался! спасибо